# Transparent SurfaceView over a transparent Activity

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have an Activity that is roughly 30-40% transparent which contains a custom View that extends SurfaceView. Everything is working as it should however the SurfaceView's background is not completely transparent (at least for the first few seconds). After 1-2 seconds (using debugger) I noticed the SurfaceView becomes completely transparent after onDraw is called from my Thread for the Canvas.

Now I'm assuming that the issue is; the canvas is selecting my activity's transparent background, creating a bitmap of it and then displaying it hence creating a double transparent overlay.

I've tried to initialize the SurfaceView first while the View is 'invisible' and enabled it after the first onDraw. No dice.

Any Suggestions or Questions?

Comment: for those viewing this issue, should I upload a section of my code to demonstrate my situation?

Comment: I am having a Transparent Activity which contains a SurfaceView. By default SurfaceView is showing transparent background. I tried setting background to container of SurfaceView but it didn't work. As per your comment to set alpha to container of ServiceView also not working for me. I want the background of SurfaceView not to be transparent.

Answer (score 1):

My SurfaceView was Embedded within a RelativeLayout View Container. By applying the alpha parameter for this view to 255 resulted in what I was looking for.

I hope someone comes across the same situation, and that this has solved their problem.